# How to filter data in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am filtering data using the method described [here](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/19) but it only hides the rows, it doesn't really filter them out. E.g.: if I type in a formula `SUM(A1:A1000)` I get the same result on the raw worksheet and the filtered worksheet. How can I filter so that the non-matching rows are excluded in the `SUM`?

Comment: adding a link why i need this http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/708616-xirr-only-visible-cells-filtered-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`SUBTOTAL`-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939). Depending on if you want to include manually hidden rows or not, you'll use either:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,A1:A1000)
```

or

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,A1:A1000)
```

The latter will not include manually hidden rows, the first one will. Both will ignore filtered out rows.

Comment: actually number 9 and 109 refers what values?

Comment: @WaQaRAli The options for the first argument of the function is detailed on the help-page linked at the top of the answer. In this case 9 and 109 both indicate that you want to sum the values in the range, while e.g. 1 / 101 would have taken the average.

Comment: SUBTOTAL is not an option as I need to compute XIRR on the filtered data